# How to add a new field in sails.js/waterline on "create"?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

My School model has a name, address, etc. and an owner which is a User object.

**School.js**

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    name: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },
    address: {
        type: 'string'
    },
    owner: {
      model: 'user'
    },
    ...
```

When creating a new school I do the following:

```
create: function(req, res, next) {
    School.create(req.params.all(), function schoolCreated (err, school) {
```

but what is the easiest way to add the owner (which after login is found in the session at req.session.user)?

I get that I can do

```
create: function(req, res, next) {
    School.create({'name': req.params.name, 'address': req.params.address, 'owner': req.session.user}, function schoolCreated (err, school) {...
```

but there must be an easier way. Any examples would help tremendously!
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer the question myself.

It looks like an elegant solution that works for me is to use the [Lo-Dash](https://lodash.com/) library to merge the request parameters with the user like this:

```
var school = _.merge(req.params.all(), {'owner': req.session.user});
```

and pass the newly created school variable to the `create` method.

```
School.create(school, function schoolCreated (err, school) {...
```